# problem binding selectOneMenu to fire and action with and ok button

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to know the selected action from a combobox to invoque methodA or methodB depending on the value selected in the combobox.

Here is my web.xhtml:

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{webUserBackingBean.selectedAction}">
                                                            <f:selectItem itemValue="a"   itemLabel="aValue" />
                                                            <f:selectItem 
                                                                            itemValue="b" itemLabel="bValue" />
                                                        </h:selectOneMenu>
```

And also:

```
<p:commandButton
                                                            id= "submitActionButton"
                                                            action="#{webUserBackingBean.executeMethod()}"
                                                            
                                                            class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-block"
                                                            style="width: 30px; margin-top: auto !important; margin-left: 10px;
                                                                                         border-color: #006cd8 !important"
                                                            value="Ok" 
...
```

When the user clicks ok webUserBackingBean.executeMethod() is fired
and in this method I have a problem:

public void executeMethod() {
...
String action = this.getSelectedAction();
...

```
}
```

Because action is always "a". Why the "b" value doesn't work even if I select it from the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

It is work fine
try this

```
`@Named
    @ViewScoped
    public class SelectMB implements Serializable {
        private String selectedAction;
        public String getSelectedAction() {
            return selectedAction;
        }
    
        public void setSelectedAction(String selectedAction) {
            this.selectedAction = selectedAction;
        }
    
        public String executeMethod() {
            System.out.println(selectedAction);
            return null;
        }
    }`

` <h:form>
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectMB.selectedAction}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="a"   itemLabel="aValue" />
            <f:selectItem
                    itemValue="b" itemLabel="bValue" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
        <p:commandButton
                id= "submitActionButton"
                action="#{selectMB.executeMethod()}"

                class="btn btn-secondary btn-md btn-block"
                style="width: 30px; margin-top: auto !important; margin-left: 10px;border-color: #006cd8 !important"
                value="Ok"/>
    </h:form>`
```